# Laravel Livewire validateOnly specific set of rules

Tags: laravel, validation

I have some forms in a livewire component and defined a full set of rules like

```
protected $rules = [
    'value'                        => 'required|string',
    'value2'                       => 'required|bool',
    'value3'                       => 'string',
    'array.quantity'               => 'required|integer|min:1',
    'array.name'                   => 'required|string|max:500',
    'array.description'            => 'required|string|max:500',
    'array.price'                  => 'required|numeric|min:1',
];
```

sometimes I validate e.g. `$this->validateOnly('value2');`

But how can I validate my "array" - which is a model? `$this->validateOnly('array.*);` or `$this->validate('array.*');` does not work.

Comment: What is `$this` in your question? I've never used the `validateOnly` method, and the only `validate` method I've used requires multiple parameters, typically `$this->validate(request()->input(), [...])`, which _might_ work in your case as `$this->validate(request()->input('array'), ['quantity' => 'required|integer|min:1', 'name' => 'required|string|max:500', 'description' => 'required|string|max:500', 'price' => 'required|numeric|min:1'])`

Comment: $this is the livewire-component

Answer (score 2):

`$this->validateOnly($propertyName)` will only let you validate one property at a time. So for instance `$this->validateOnly('array.price')` will validate the price.

The only way to implement the behavior you want, with a single array would be like this:

```php
function validateArray() {
    foreach($this->array as $key => $value) {
        $this->validateOnly(sprintf('array.%s', $key));
    }
}
```

But I don't think this is a very clean solution. So as @Tim already commented, I'd create a seperate rules property, like this:

```php
protected $rules = [
    'value'                        => 'required|string',
    'value2'                       => 'required|bool',
    'value3'                       => 'string',
];

protected $arrayRules = [
    'quantity'               => 'required|integer|min:1',
    'name'                   => 'required|string|max:500',
    'description'            => 'required|string|max:500',
    'price'                  => 'required|numeric|min:1',
];

$this->validate($array, $this->arrayRules);
```

Comment: I actually had the same thought re: approach as you did, but I wasn't sure if `->validateOnly()` would work in a loop. If it behaves like `->validate()` does, and redirects on failure, it would only ever validate 1 incorrect rule, which would work, but wouldn't be the best UI/UX if the user then has to fix the problems one-by-one.

Comment: @TimLewis It'll definitly redirect on the first failure using the loop, so from a UI/UX pov the second option would always be better

Comment: thanks, never thought of using a second $rules ... 
just wanted to give it a try, but as the array is in fact a model, livewire throws an exception because model property must exist in `$rules`.

so I ended up in extracting the rules for single values into a `$otherRules` and validate them with `$this->validate('value', $this->otherRules)`.

I think livewire 3 will have an impact on this topic with forms